# Slow Response Time - Google APIs Geocoding and Recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha, google-geocoding-api

Regarding my Google APIs, recaptcha and geocoding, I've checked the configuration of my Google Account and everything looks fine. The queries all reach an OK status. HOWEVER, the queries all take more than a minute to get a response. Like I said, I haven't found anything abnormal and quotas are neither being reached nor exceeded. Why are the response times so slow? Is this coming from Google? The fact that I don't have billing activated on my account?

How else can I determine what is causing this and reduce response time?

ETA:

Our configuration files were checked over yesterday and they are perfectly fine (public as well as private keys)
The methods I used were JSON or CURL and yet, the problem of excessive response times still persists.

1. Example Get :

   ```
       $address = urlencode($address);
           $url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=XXXXXXXKEYXXXXXXX&sensor=false&address=$address";
           $resp_json = file_get_contents($url);
           $resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);

       $lati = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
       $longi = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
       $formatted_address = $resp['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
       echo $resp['status'].">>".$formatted_address;
   ```
2. Exemple Curl:

   ```
       $ch = curl_init($url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
       $parsed = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);

   print_r($parsed);
   ```

Comment: Could you post your configuration files? Beware your sensitive data.

Comment: Only can say that billing activation not affect response time in my case. I use both (recaptcha and geocoding) API without a billning activation and the response is very fast